# How can i add property on returning node depending upon relationship exist or not in NEO4J

Tags: neo4j

In neo4j i have two node labels. Users and Groups. I want to get all groups and want to add property on return in groups if that group has relationship with the user i select.

For example,

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE ID(u) = 81
WITH u
MATCH (g:Groups)
WITH g
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[c:CREATED]-(g)
return g,ID(c)
```

Output of above query is

```
g
name    vishal
image   ca1f4ed2658a1855cebe21c006291e78.jpg
description vishal

ID(c)
339
```

**I want to add property in g if relationship exist as g.create= true else g.create = false. I don't want to set this property in database.** I just want to return it with additional property. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (u:User), (g:Groups)
WHERE ID(u) = 81
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[c:CREATED]-(g)
return {group: g, created: NOT(c IS NULL)} AS result, ID(c);
```

The `result` object contains a `Groups` node and a separate `created` boolean value.

Comment: can be shorter you don't need the intermediate match on groups but pull the label into the optional match.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Actually, I have updated my answer to merge the 2 `MATCH` statements, which is more in keeping with the original query. We want to see all the `Groups` nodes, or else `created` would always be `true`.

Comment: Your answer is correct but i was facing problem reading group object from result. So without returning it in single object as result i updated it to return separately and than assigned it inside group object.